# How to read json object returned from service in c#\Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, json, deserialization

This is probably a simple\newbie question but I'm using a service that returns json, as such

> {   "employees" : [
>       {
>         "id" : "1",
>         "name" : john smith"
>       }   ] }

I'm trying to read the returned json, as per the code below.  If I debug the "e.Result.Length" is correct so I assume the service is ok and return the correct info.

But my issue is how do I get the info out of the e.Result?

I'm using the DataContractJsonSerializer incorrectly, both ways I get null objects or null properties?

Are there other ways to read the return value or for that matter calling the service?

Note I'm doing this in Silverlight so if there is a preferred way or different methods to do this I'll like to know.

Thanks

```
private void CallService(string url){
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += completed;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url));
}
private void completed(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //tried this
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(employee));
    var emps= jsonSerializer.ReadObject(e.Result) as employee;
    //and tried this
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<employee>));
    var emps= jsonSerializer.ReadObject(e.Result) as List<employee>;
}
[DataContract]
internal class employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id;
    [DataMember]
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: One other thing to note it the fact that in your code the employee class is internal, that might cause some casting issues.  Not sure but just thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a contract for the whole result

```
[DataContract]
internal class Result
{
   [DataMember]
   public employee[] Employees {get; set;}
}
```

Then pass that in

```
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Result));
```